# Manually insert Data from database in table which has hibernate_sequence @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)

Tags: java, oracle, postgresql, hibernate

I have table with ID @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE). Need to insert  800  records manually on postgresql production database.We had migration from oracle to postgresql , few User mistakenly access old link and data inserted in oracle .  Please explain how to maintain hibernate_sequence in this case. As its production database.

Comment: I'm wondering why you use TABLE and not SEQUENCE because both databases are supporting it and it may be much better for performance.

Answer (score 1):

In the first step check your key generation table and the `SEQUENCE_NAME`.

If you use the default setting you will see something as follows - adapt the further steps for different configuration.

```
select * from hibernate_sequences;

SEQUENCE_NAME   NEXT_VAL
--------------- ----------
default         nnnnn
```

Now increase the `NEXT_VAL` by the requested number of the skipped records. To avoid the problem of concurent insert via Hibernate I use `LOCK TABLE` - all insert from Hibernate are blocked until you finish the action bellow.

```
lock table hibernate_sequences in exclusive mode;
select * from hibernate_sequences;
-- remember the value of NEXT_VAL nnnn
update hibernate_sequences
set NEXT_VAL = NEXT_VAL + 800
where SEQUENCE_NAME = 'default';
commit;
```

Now you have 800 `ID`'s nnnn + 1 .. nnnn + 800 to be used for your skipped rows.

*Note that the `LOCK` will work if you connect with the OWNER of the table `hibernate_sequences`. You may skip the `LOCK` at all if the application is down and no insert can be performed.*

Use the identical `INSERT` as you see in Hibernate `show_sql` and with your data pass the reserved ID.

Example

```
-- Hibernate: insert into AUTHOR (name, AUTHOR_ID) values (?, ?)
insert into AUTHOR (name, AUTHOR_ID) values ('Psik', nnnn +1);
insert into AUTHOR (name, AUTHOR_ID) values ('Tuzka', nnnn+2);
```

**Warning**

As mentioned in comment, you should plan to switch to `SEQUENCE` mapping, which would make the adding of skipped rows even simpler. See also [why-you-should-never-use-the-table-identifier-generator-with-jpa-and-hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-never-use-the-table-identifier-generator-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

Having said that, the `TABLE` generator could work fine for some use cases e.g. with low number of concurrent inserts. Using similar argumentation the claim could be: *why-you-should-never-use-the-jpa-and-hibernate* if performance matter.