# Integration test on H2 errors on unique index violation - Stale id sequence after the test @Sql data loading?

Tags: jpa, spring-boot-test, unique-constraint

The error message is:

```
Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.LAYOUT(ID) ( /* key:1 */ CAST(1 AS BIGINT), 'My simple layout', CAST(1 AS BIGINT))"; SQL statement:
insert into layout (name, profile_id, id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

The full console output:

```
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.5)

2023-05-10T11:16:05.732+02:00  INFO 1302958 --- [           main] c.t.s.controller.LayoutControllerTest    : Starting LayoutControllerTest using Java 17.0.1 with PID 1302958 (started by stephane in /home/stephane/dev/java/projects/sql-fetch-all)
2023-05-10T11:16:05.734+02:00  INFO 1302958 --- [           main] c.t.s.controller.LayoutControllerTest    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-05-10T11:16:06.576+02:00  INFO 1302958 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-05-10T11:16:06.678+02:00  INFO 1302958 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 84 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-05-10T11:16:07.286+02:00  INFO 1302958 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-05-10T11:16:07.521+02:00  INFO 1302958 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:9c41a542-2a01-4464-8528-da45f652e5fd user=SA
2023-05-10T11:16:07.523+02:00  INFO 1302958 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-05-10T11:16:07.575+02:00  INFO 1302958 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-05-10T11:16:07.622+02:00  INFO 1302958 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-05-10T11:16:07.970+02:00  INFO 1302958 --- [           main] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2023-05-10T11:16:09.024+02:00  INFO 1302958 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-05-10T11:16:09.034+02:00  INFO 1302958 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-05-10T11:16:09.890+02:00  WARN 1302958 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-05-10T11:16:10.320+02:00  INFO 1302958 --- [           main] o.s.b.t.m.w.SpringBootMockServletContext : Initializing Spring TestDispatcherServlet ''
2023-05-10T11:16:10.320+02:00  INFO 1302958 --- [           main] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Initializing Servlet ''
2023-05-10T11:16:10.324+02:00  INFO 1302958 --- [           main] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2023-05-10T11:16:10.354+02:00  INFO 1302958 --- [           main] c.t.s.controller.LayoutControllerTest    : Started LayoutControllerTest in 4.985 seconds (process running for 6.219)
2023-05-10T11:16:10.773+02:00  WARN 1302958 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23505, SQLState: 23505
2023-05-10T11:16:10.773+02:00 ERROR 1302958 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.LAYOUT(ID) ( /* key:1 */ CAST(1 AS BIGINT), 'My simple layout', CAST(1 AS BIGINT))"; SQL statement:
insert into layout (name, profile_id, id) values (?, ?, ?) [23505-214]
2023-05-10T11:16:10.775+02:00  INFO 1302958 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.997 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.thalasoft.sqlfetchall.controller.LayoutControllerTest
[ERROR] should_create_one  Time elapsed: 0.435 s  <<< ERROR!
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: 
Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.LAYOUT(ID) ( /* key:1 */ CAST(1 AS BIGINT), 'My simple layout', CAST(1 AS BIGINT))"; SQL statement:
insert into layout (name, profile_id, id) values (?, ?, ?) [23505-214]]
    at com.thalasoft.sqlfetchall.controller.LayoutControllerTest.should_create_one(LayoutControllerTest.java:74)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: 
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.LAYOUT(ID) ( /* key:1 */ CAST(1 AS BIGINT), 'My simple layout', CAST(1 AS BIGINT))"; SQL statement:
insert into layout (name, profile_id, id) values (?, ?, ?) [23505-214]]
    at com.thalasoft.sqlfetchall.controller.LayoutControllerTest.should_create_one(LayoutControllerTest.java:74)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at com.thalasoft.sqlfetchall.controller.LayoutControllerTest.should_create_one(LayoutControllerTest.java:74)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.LAYOUT(ID) ( /* key:1 */ CAST(1 AS BIGINT), 'My simple layout', CAST(1 AS BIGINT))"; SQL statement:
insert into layout (name, profile_id, id) values (?, ?, ?) [23505-214]
    at com.thalasoft.sqlfetchall.controller.LayoutControllerTest.should_create_one(LayoutControllerTest.java:74)

2023-05-10T11:16:10.855+02:00  INFO 1302958 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-05-10T11:16:10.856+02:00  INFO 1302958 --- [ionShutdownHook] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2023-05-10T11:16:10.868+02:00  INFO 1302958 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-05-10T11:16:10.873+02:00  INFO 1302958 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

The test case is:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@DisplayNameGeneration(DisplayNameGenerator.ReplaceUnderscores.class)
@SqlGroup({
  @Sql(value = "classpath:fixture/data.reset.sql", executionPhase = BEFORE_TEST_METHOD),
  @Sql(value = "classpath:fixture/data.init.sql", executionPhase = BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
})
public class LayoutControllerTest {

  @Test
  void should_create_one() throws Exception {
    final File jsonFile = new ClassPathResource("fixture/data.layout.json").getFile();
    final String content = Files.readString(jsonFile.toPath());

    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/layout/create/{profileId}", 1)
        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content(content))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isCreated())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$").isMap())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$", aMapWithSize(4)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value("Another name"));

    assertThat(this.layoutRepository.findAll()).hasSize(1);
  }
```

The SQL data files are:

```
SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY   FALSE;
TRUNCATE TABLE layout RESTART IDENTITY;
TRUNCATE TABLE profile RESTART IDENTITY;
TRUNCATE TABLE profile_type RESTART IDENTITY;
TRUNCATE TABLE product RESTART IDENTITY;
TRUNCATE TABLE product_part RESTART IDENTITY;
TRUNCATE TABLE layout_product RESTART IDENTITY;
SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY   TRUE;

INSERT INTO profile_type (id, profile_type_enum) VALUES (1, 'CAR');

INSERT INTO profile (id, profile_type_id) VALUES (1, 1);

INSERT INTO layout (id, name, profile_id) VALUES (1, 'My simple layout', 1);

INSERT INTO product (id, name, supplier) VALUES (1, 'Lamp', 'Sun');

INSERT INTO product_part (id, name, serial_number, product_id) VALUES (1, 'Shade', 'AA123FR', 1);
INSERT INTO product_part (id, name, serial_number, product_id) VALUES (2, 'Bulb', 'BF43944', 1);
INSERT INTO product_part (id, name, serial_number, product_id) VALUES (3, 'Cable', 'KF84324', 1);

INSERT INTO layout_product (id, layout_id, product_id) VALUES (1, 1, 1);
```

The json file for the posted content:

```
{ "name": "Another name" }
```

The test properties:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:demo;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    username: sa
    password:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    defer-datasource-initialization: true

spring:
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always
```

The entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "layout")
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Layout {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  private String name;

  @NotNull
  @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Profile profile;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="layout", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private Set<LayoutProduct> layoutProducts;

  public void addProduct(LayoutProduct layoutProduct) {
    layoutProducts.add(layoutProduct);
    layoutProduct.setLayout(this);
  }

  public void removeProduct(LayoutProduct layoutProduct) {
    layoutProducts.remove(layoutProduct);
    layoutProduct.setLayout(null);
  }
}
```

The repository is:

```
@Repository
public interface LayoutRepository extends JpaRepository<Layout, Long> {

  @Query("SELECT new com.thalasoft.sqlfetchall.data.model.domain.projection.LayoutView(l, pf, pt, lp, pd) FROM LayoutProduct lp JOIN lp.layout l JOIN l.profile pf JOIN pf.profileType pt JOIN lp.product pd WHERE l.id = :id")
  List<LayoutView> findByIdFetching(@Param("id") Long id);

}
```

The controller is:

```
  @PostMapping("/create/{profileId}")
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  public LayoutGetDto create(@PathVariable("profileId") Long profileId, @RequestBody LayoutPostDto layoutDto) {
    layoutDto.setProfileDto(this.layoutMapper.entityToDto(profileService.findById(profileId)));
    LayoutGetDto ldto = this.layoutMapper.entityToDto(this.layoutService.create(this.layoutMapper.dtoToEntity(layoutDto)));
    return ldto;
  }
```

The service is:

```
  public Layout create(Layout layout) {
    final var newLayout = Layout.builder()
        .name(layout.getName())
        .profile(layout.getProfile())
        .build();
    return this.layoutRepository.save(newLayout);
  }
```

The error is triggered by the `this.layoutRepository.save(newLayout);` call.

The debugger shows the expected json content for the `newLayout` object.

Note that the name of the layout failing to be inserted is not the name found in the json content file but it is the name found in the loaded data.

The other test cases on finding one or all and on deleting do pass all right.

If I remove the following SQL statements:

```
INSERT INTO layout (id, name, profile_id) VALUES (1, 'My simple layout', 1);
INSERT INTO layout_product (id, layout_id, product_id) VALUES (1, 1, 1);
```

in another copy of the data file used only by the failing test, then the test passes fine. So the test originally fails because it tries to add a layout when another one already exists with the same id value.

The strange thing is this output:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.LAYOUT(ID) ( /* key:1 */ CAST(1 AS BIGINT), 'My simple layout', CAST(1 AS BIGINT))"; SQL statement:
insert into layout (name, profile_id, id) values (?, ?, ?) [23505-214]]
```

Does this mean the test is trying to insert the layout with name `My simple layout` ? Or does this mean that this layout already exists in the database and is the source of the conflict ?

The project is on Java 17 with spring-boot-starter-parent 3.0.5

I have already seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71340181/spring-boot-test-with-sql-h2-gives-jdbcsqlintegrityconstraintviolationexcepti) and tried to act on its answer but it changed nothing in the error.

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61121870/958373) I suspect the issue comes from the sequence id generator which is not updated after the data loading. So the data loading inserts a layout and later on the test tries to insert a layout with the id value of `1` since its sequence has not been updated on the data loading. That is just a guess..

I also tried replacing the id generation strategy: `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)` by `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` but it changed nothing in the error.

UPDATE: I edited the data loading file to replace the layout id of value `1` by the value `2` as in:

```
INSERT INTO layout (id, name, profile_id) VALUES (2, 'My simple layout', 1);
INSERT INTO layout_product (id, layout_id, product_id) VALUES (1, 2, 1);
```

and all the tests passed all right.

This tells me that the id sequence is not refreshed after the manual insert with the layout id value of `1` and the sequence still offers the same value of `1` to the insert of the test, which results in a constraint violation.

Answer (score 0):

As you explained in your latest update about root cause of the problem, base on this strategy `GenerationType.IDENTITY` for id column.

1. if you need `id` value for the other script as `FK` column (like your case) it's better to use large numbers that your business never meets it, like 1000.
2. if you don't need id value in other data sql statements, it better to skip this column for insertion.